# Compiling and linking c++ program - make file

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I'm building a make file for my program.
The main is on: twitServer.cpp
and its using:  Command.h Client.h

I built a make file and it doesn't seems to work.
Can you help me figure out?

```
twitServer: twitServer.o Command.o Client.o
     g++ -Wall -o twitServer.o Command.o Client.o twitServer

twitServer.o: twitServer.cpp Command.h Client.h
     g++ -c -Wall twitServer.cpp

Command.o: Command.cpp Command.h
     g++ -c -Wall Command.cpp

Client.o: Client.cpp Client.h
     g++ -c -Wall Client.cpp

clean:
     rm twitServer Client.o Command.o Client.o
```

My Error is:
g++: twitServer: No such file or directory

Although I got all this files: 
Client.cpp  Client.o     Command.h  Makefile   twitServer.cpp
Client.h    Command.cpp  Command.o  Makefile~  twitServer.o

Comment: Please elaborate somewhat on 'doesn't seem to work'. Do you get errors?

Comment: Are you sure you have the TAB special characters at the beginning of commands? (before g++). What is the error message you get when you try to run that makefile?

Comment: This is the error: g++: twitServer: No such file or directory

Comment: @ondav yes, I have it, thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
g++ -Wall -o twitServer.o Command.o Client.o twitServer
```

is wrong. You don't want the compiler to output to `twitServer.o` **and** link the `twitServer` file, do you? Those two should be flipped, like this:

```
g++ -Wall -o twitServer Command.o Client.o twitServer.o
```

Comment: Thanks, but now After fixing, I'm trying to run the program and get: twitServer: command not found

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm Read my comments on the other answer or do I need to repeat them here?

Answer (score 1):

Change the position of the `-o` flag:

```
twitServer: twitServer.o Command.o Client.o
     g++ -Wall twitServer.o Command.o Client.o -o twitServer
```

Comment: Thanks, But now I get: twitServer: command not found
While trying to run the program

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm `./twitServer`

Comment: Why is that ? How can I make it to run without ./?

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm Put it into one of the directories in `$PATH`, for example `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Wait, sorry for bothering, but I made makefiles in the past, and I could make a runnable  file inside my directory. without using ./

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm I doubt that. What shell did you use?

Comment: You can add `.` to your path but it is a **very** bad idea. `export PATH+=:.`

Comment: Maybe it was different computer, now I'm using Konsole on Ubuntu